# Can we travel from Japan to USA with Indian US visa?

Tags: visas, usa, japan, indian-citizens, b1-b2-visas

I am an Indian. I have a tourist visa for visiting USA and Japan. Can I travel to Japan first, tour there for a month and then travel to USA directly from Japan?. Or Should I come back to India after visiting Japan and then travel back from India to Japan?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to come back to India, because the visa does not dictate where you should start your journey.

You can fly to Japan, spend some time there, and from Japan fly to the US. For immigration, it would be just the same as if you flew from India (or anywhere else).

The visa guarantees you entry to the border point, and it does not dictate anything more (or less).

Comment: "The visa guarantees you entry to the border point" is not universally true (in particular, it is not true in Japan). If you meant to say it is true in the US (I have no idea whether that's the case), maybe you could make this explicit.

Comment: What is the exception in Japan? A visa just means you can travel to the border check (which is what I meant). It does not guarantee you entry into the country.

Comment: Then I'm not sure what you meant exactly... Getting you to the border is the airline's job, and while it is true that they will deny you boarding if you don't have a visa despite needing one, they can also do it for a lot of other reasons.

Comment: Its not the airline's job - you can travel by car to the border check - and to cross into immigration you would need a visa, but just holding a visa does not guarantee you entry into the country. For example, the immigration officer can refuse you entry if you do not carry supporting documents for the type of travel indicated on your visa.

Comment: You can travel by car even without a visa. ;) My point is that a visa does not guarantee anything. It's only one part of the procedure to enter a country.

Comment: I think we are making the same point :)

Comment: Yes but in your answer you say "The visa guarantees you [...]", which can be confusing.